# Deserialized JSON String to C# Object gives the error "Cannot access static class in non-static context" when the object's methods are called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, json.net

I'm trying to GET a JSON REST-api request, deserialize it using the Newtonsoft.Json package for .NET and access methods within the newly created object, but I keep getting an error that won't let me run my C# code in Visual Studio 2015.

For the following JSON string,

```
{
    "pagination": 
    {
        "per_page": 1,
        "items": 28, 
        "page": 1, 
        "urls": 
        {
            "last": "https://...",
            "next": "https://..."
        },
        "pages": 28
    },
    "results": 
    [{
        "style": ["House"],
        "thumb": "https://...", 
        "format": ["File", "AAC", "Album"], 
        "country": "Unknown", 
        "barcode": ["id886037928"], 
        "uri": "/Porter-Robinson-Worlds/master/721049", 
        "community": {"have": 932, "want": 720}, 
        "label": ["Astralwerks", "Sample Sized, LLC", "Astralwerks"], 
        "catno": "none", 
        "year": "2014", 
        "genre": ["Electronic"], 
        "title": "Porter Robinson - Worlds", 
        "resource_url": "https://...", 
        "type": "master", 
        "id": 721049
    }]
}
```

I created the following C# object class:

```
public class Discogs
{
    public class pagination
    {
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public int items { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }

        public class urls
        {
            public string last { get; set; }
            public string next { get; set; }

        }

        public int pages { get; set; }


        public class data
        {
            public string[] style { get; set; }
            public string thumb { get; set; }
            public string[] format { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string[] barcode { get; set; }
            public string uri { get; set; }

            public class community
            {
                public string have { get; set; }
                public string want { get; set; }
            }

            public string[] label { get; set; }
            public string catno { get; set; }
            public string year { get; set; }
            public string[] genre { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string resource_url { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }
        public class results
        {
            public data Results { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In a `private async void class`, I've successfully fetched the GET request and stored it in the string, `jsonstring`. Now I try to run this code:

```
Discogs myUser = new Discogs();
myUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Discogs>(jsonstring);
int yr = myUser.pagination.data.year;
```

...but my project gets an error, *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Discogs.pagination.data.year'*, *cannot access non-static property 'year' in static context.*

This does not make sense to me because I have no static classes or methods. I've searched for a solution but all similar problems seem to be able to access deserialized objects without any such error. Any help on accessing the methods in my Discogs object would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use the class `Pagination` without instantiating the class.  In order to use a non-static class (Pagination, Data, Community) you must first instantiate them like below

```
Pagination pag = new Pagination();
```

Your structure here is pretty odd.  Normally classes would be in separate files or at least not nested such as you have here.  You may want to rethink the way you've designed this program.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know we could have nested classes. Not that I'm going to use it ever, just didn't know C# supported this feature.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!!! I can't believe the first answer, within a couple minutes solved a problem I've been stuck with for hours. I didn't realize that classes nested within other classes also had to be instantiated. I wanted to challenge myself initially and create an object for my json query from scratch but I took your advice and auto-created the object using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). It rearranged my entire structure without needing nested classes and now all my data is displaying properly. Again, thank you so much!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get value from "myUser.pagination...", but in your example "pagination" is a class name not a property inside "Discogs" class, same as "data" inside "pagination" class

code with nested classes:

```
public class Discogs
{
    public class Pagination
    {
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public int items { get; set; }
        public int page { get; set; }

        public class Urls
        {
            public string last { get; set; }
            public string next { get; set; }

        }

        public Urls urls {get;set;}

        public int pages { get; set; }

        public class Data
        {
            public string[] style { get; set; }
            public string thumb { get; set; }
            public string[] format { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string[] barcode { get; set; }
            public string uri { get; set; }

            public class Community
            {
                public string have { get; set; }
                public string want { get; set; }
            }

            public Community community { get; set; }

            public string[] label { get; set; }
            public string catno { get; set; }
            public string year { get; set; }
            public string[] genre { get; set; }
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string resource_url { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Results
        {
            public Data Results { get; set; }
        }

        public Results result {get;set;}
    }

    public Pagination pagination {get;set}
}
```

code with i think a bit easy to understand:

```
public class Urls
{
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }

}

public class Community
{
    public string have { get; set; }
    public string want { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string[] style { get; set; }
    public string thumb { get; set; }
    public string[] format { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string[] barcode { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public string[] label { get; set; }
    public string catno { get; set; }
    public string year { get; set; }
    public string[] genre { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string resource_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

    public Community community { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public Data Results { get; set; }
}       

public class Pagination
{
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public int items { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int pages { get; set; }

    public Urls urls {get;set;}
    public Results result {get;set;}
}

public class Discogs
{
    public Pagination pagination {get;set}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding on Tim's answer! I have a much better understanding of nested classes because of your answer now. Thanks!